# Changing container using FFMPEG produces NAL unit error

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264, rtp, mkv

**Background:**

My current videofile is put in a Linux based system that streams content (RTP) to other users. I'm filming and sending the content to the server after I change the and make sure the encoding is correct I stumble upon issues.

I've tried doing this using `ffmpeg`, however the system I'm injecting this file in won't recognize it and stream it to another device.

I'm doing all the transcoding and such on a Windows system

```
C:\Users\mazdak\Documents\Projects\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 4.1 -color_range 0 -colorspace bt709 -x264opts colorprim=bt709:transfer=bt709:bframes=1 -an output.mkv
```

**Error:**
What I'm getting is

```
    StreamMedia exception ry: Unexpected NAL unit type: 9
    (...)
    StreamMedia exception ry: First media frame must be sync point
```

Maybe I'm not preparing it for RTSP? Is that the issue. Cause what I see is that the files that are able to stream are encoded using *Gstreamer*

So I thought.. perhaps `ffmpeg` does not do that? well let's give `gst-launch` a try.
I need pointers as to how to go about this.

**What I have:**

- OSSBuild of GStreamer
- `ffmpeg utils`
- `input.mp4` - H264 Main profile L3.1 - Pixel format yuvj420p
- Audio in container

**What I need (probably):**

- `output.mkv`- H264 Main profile L4.1 - Pixel format yuv420p - RTP prepared (rtph264pay module)
- Audio removed

I have `h264_analyze` output from both the movie I filmed. From the movie that is successfully streamed, and the movies from my attempts with `ffmpeg`

Comment: What system are you using to stream the content?  What does it state in its documentation about what file formats it can handle?

Comment: @mpr The system is a streaming server running on a Linux based OS. The only format it can handle is the matroska container with h264 coded content.

Comment: So the desired output is an mkv.  Is your input an mp4 or another mkv?  I see conflicting info in your description and sample code.  If all you're trying to do is convert mp4 to mkv that's something GStreamer can do, but the pipeline will vary depending on whether you want to add the audio tracks and perhaps some other factors.  Are you doing the conversion in Windows or in Linux?  Also, what created the input video?  It may be the problem if ffmpeg couldn't handle it.  Note that RTP/RTSP really only deals with the streaming side of things.  It doesn't affect the correctness of mp4/mkv files.

Comment: @mpr Sorry! I accidentally changed the format when I changed the name. 
Changed it and added more info to the question that should cover your questions in the comments.
I'm trying to change the format from .mp4 to .mkv. Running a Windows 7 with ffmpeg and gstreamer built for windows. A digital camera produces "input.mp4" with audio. I don't want the audio in "output.mkv".

Answer (score 1):

So this question can go in a whole bunch of different directions depending on what you're trying to do.  Here is a very basic pipeline that just re-muxes h264 video data in an mp4 file into an mkv file.  It ignores the audio.  No re-encoding is necessary.

> gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="bbb.mp4" ! qtdemux ! video/x-h264 !
> h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=/tmp/bbb.mkv

Here is another pipeline that demuxes an mp4 file, re-encodes it using the out-of-the-box x264 settings, and re-muxes it into an mkv file.

> gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location="bbb.mp4" ! decodebin2 !
> videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink
> location=/tmp/bbb2.mkv

Video formats are usually more like a bundle of data than an individual file.  A the top level you have your container formats (mp4, mkv, etc.), then often within those containers you have video and audio data stored in various formats (h264 video, AAC audio, etc.).  Then at the streaming level you have protocols like RTP (RTSP is a sort of wrapper protocol for negotiating one or more RTP streams) and MPEGTS.

You may also want to double check what your camera is producing.  You can run ffprobe on it:

> ffprobe whatever.mp4

You can also try creating simple test videos from scratch to see if GStreamer can even make anything your server can understand.

> gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc num-buffers=120 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc profile=main ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=/tmp/main.mkv
>
> gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc num-buffers=120 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc profile=baseline ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=/tmp/baseline.mkv
>
> gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc num-buffers=120 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc profile=high ! h264parse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=/tmp/high.mkv

Comment: Seems like a great pipeline and thank you for the explanation. Still getting the error though =/

Comment: Are you running GStreamer 0.10 or 1.0?  What is the name of the video server software you're using?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that input.mp4 contains NAL of type 9 (as the error message points out).
"Access unit delimiters" (NAL type 9) should not be in an mp4.

To me it looks like your camera is muxing an illegal h.264 bitstream format into input.mp4.

MP4s should contain size prefixed NALs and no SPS (type 7), PPS (type 8) or AUs (type 9).

Now the question is how to filter out the AUs or just pass them through.

I would try a stream copy - dropping the audio - see: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy